# transposing data with macro

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to transpose my data using a loop and not the typical transpose function so I don't have to merge the data with unused variables.

Data I have is the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4), Amount=c(100, 150, 75, 50), 
    Month=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))
```

Which gives the following results:

```
ID Amount Month
1    100   Jan
2    150   Feb
3     75   Mar
4     50   Apr
```

I would like the final results to be like this:

```
ID Amount Jan Feb Mar Apr
1    100   1   0   0   0
2    150   0   1   0   0
3     75   0   0   1   0
4     50   0   0   0   1
```

I would know how to do this in SAS but couldn't find a solution with R.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library('tidyr')
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4), Amount=c(100, 150, 75, 50), 
                  Month=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))
df1$ID <- 1
df1 <- spread(df1 , Month, ID, fill=0)
df1
```

will result in:

```
  Amount Apr Feb Jan Mar
1     50   1   0   0   0
2     75   0   0   0   1
3    100   0   0   1   0
4    150   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: if you don't have `tidyr` installed, try `install.packages('tidyr')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `table`

```
cbind(df1, as.data.frame.matrix(table(lapply(df1[-1], 
                         function(x) factor(x, levels = unique(x))))))
```